# Iterate through array of objects to return the key with greatest value sum

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
const repos = [
  { JavaScript: 82061, CSS: 4992, HTML: 1992 },
  { Ruby: 47816, HTML: 8638, JavaScript: 4419, CSS: 1842 },
  { CSS: 5006, JavaScript: 812, HTML: 336 },
  { Ruby: 1898 },
];
```

I have an API response.

Each object in the array represents a users Github repository. I want to calculate what their preferred language is based on total size (or lines written in said language), with the possibility of it being other languages that might show up.

I'm looking for a method that in this case would return "Javascript"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start off by using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to get a single object with all the language types summed (`totals` object below).

After doing this, you can turn this object into an array of `[key, value]` pairs using [Object.entries](http://localhost/node/doc-offline/out/docs/web/javascript/reference/global_objects/object/entries/), and then run a second reduce on it to get the language with the max line count.

```js
const repos = [
  { JavaScript: 82061, CSS: 4992, HTML: 1992 },
  { Ruby: 47816, HTML: 8638, JavaScript: 4419, CSS: 1842 },
  { CSS: 5006, JavaScript: 812, HTML: 336 },
  { Ruby: 1898 }
];

const totals = repos.reduce((a, o) => {
  for (const k of Object.keys(o)) {
    a[k] = (a[k] || 0) + o[k];
  }
  return a;
}, {});

const max = Object.entries(totals).reduce((a, o) => o[1] > a[1] ? o : a);

console.log('most used language:', max[0], ', total lines:', max[1]);
```

Comment: @BenStephens: good catch, thanks...answer modified as you suggested.

Comment: @BenStephens I'm sincerely glad you posted the alternative answer, thank you! It's always interesting to me to see how other coders approach a problem. I like that your method avoids block functions, and the use of chaining rather my use of an intermediate variable.

Answer (score 1):

Fork of @David784's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67863277/14454939) (please give them any credit) because I don't like for loops in reduce for some reason.

```js
const repos = [
  { JavaScript: 82061, CSS: 4992, HTML: 1992 },
  { Ruby: 47816, HTML: 8638, JavaScript: 4419, CSS: 1842 },
  { CSS: 5006, JavaScript: 812, HTML: 336 },
  { Ruby: 1898 }
];

const merge_in_object = (obj1, obj2) =>
  Object.keys(obj2).reduce(
    (a, v) => Object.assign(a, { [v]: (a[v] || 0) + obj2[v] }),
    obj1
  );

const get_totals = (array) => array.reduce(merge_in_object, {});

const max = Object
  .entries(get_totals(repos))
  .reduce((a, o) => o[1] > a[1] ? o : a);

console.log('most used language:', max[0], ', total lines:', max[1]);
```